# Ensuring resiliency of a Node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

My application uses a Node.js backend. The developers are careful to make sure there are no uncaught exceptions and unhandled promise rejections that may cause the node process to exit. However, there is still a chance that an unpredicted situation may arise and the process will crash. We'd like to minimize the impact on users. We are considering a combination of the following:

1. Having a try/catch for all HTTP requests and socket.io event handlers and making sure unexpected errors are reported back to the end user without impacting others.
2. Running multiple Docker containers in AWS ECS (we are in AWS) across multiple AZs. If one crashes, others can pick up the workload until the crashed one is back up.
3. In addition to multiple Docker containers, we are considering using Node.js `[cluster][1]` module to further contain crashes. A Docker container may take as long as a minute to restart, but workers can be respawned in under a second. Workers also contain the crash to only those users that were on a particular worker, thus reducing the impact. I also feel that `cluster` ends up helping with a more efficient use of computing resources.

Ultimately, my recommendation as an architect would be to apply all three techniques.

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Utilities like PM2 daemonize Node processes and automatically restart them upon crash, aren't you using PM2?

Comment: We are using Docker and AWS ECS, so for the moment allowing ECS to automatically restart upon a crash. What does PM2 give us that `cluster` does not?

Comment: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Comment: I like it, it does what cluster does without any code changes. The devs will like it.

Comment: + system monitoring and all